# NullPointerException related to FragmentManager.popBackStack. How to resolve?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have an Android app where I have an activity and a stack of fragments.

Using Crashlytics, I have received a single instance of the following `Exception`:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.FragmentManager.popBackStack(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
       at com.company.app.Fragment$7$2.onClick(Fragment.java:397)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

The code that is producing this error is:

```
okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        // The next line produces the Exception
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Other code...
        }, 250);
    }
});
```

Based on the testing I have done with this app, the user for which this Exception occurred, and the fact that is has only occurred once, I am thinking that this `Exception` occurs when some strange consolidation of circumstances occurs. (Basically, I can't reproduce this `Exception` on my end.) I am assuming this has to do with the user backgrounding my app and then resuming it at a later time, and then the `getFragmentManager()` call returns a `null`.

So, I know that I can "fix" this with code like the following (found this as an applied fix to a GitHub repository):

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
if (fm != null) fm.popBackStack();
```

While I realize that the code above will "fix" the problem in that it will avoid the `NPE`, (thus stopping the app from crashing), it doesn't really "fix" the problem by allowing my app to function as desired. The `Fragment` in question is #3 in a stack of fragments, like this:

```
#1 --> #2 --> #3
```

The desired behavior for the app is to respond to this button click by popping back to `Fragment` #1 being visible. Merely adding in the code above seems like it would keep the app from crashing, but not change the app's UI in the desired manner.

What am I doing wrong such that when my app resumes, it's "fragment state" is out of whack?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, I call getFragmentManager().popBackStack() on a button to close the fragment and come back to the previous one. I also cannot reproduce it but the bug is frequent enough to be a real problem.

Comment: i am facing this problem now 
have you find a solution ??

Answer (score 0):

I have never faced an issue with the getFragmentManager() being null so I am assuming it is the popBack part of the statement that is causing the issue.  Here is one possible solution to prevent a crash and handling the exceptions. If it only happened once, it may have been a rare instance.

```
okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager() != null) {
            // Assuming the getFragmentManager() is not the Issue, rather the popBackStack is the issue
            try {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Recreate a new instance of your first fragment here.
            }
        } else {
            /*
             getFragmentManager() == null 
             I have never faced an issue when getFragmentManager() == null, but I would restart the activity if that is the case
            */

        }
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        }, 250);
    }
});
```