# Fragment manager throws nullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment, fragmentmanager

i have an application with one activity and fragments,i am navigating between fragment using this

```
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .replace(R.id.mainContainer, postesFragment)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

i have a fragment with sub-fragments(using viewPager), when i add it its ok, and pop it using

> fragmentManager.popBackStack()

here is no problem, but when i add another fragment to the backstack above this, and i pop it the application crashes due to this exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                                at android.app.BackStackRecord.setBackNameOverrides(BackStackRecord.java:1683)
                                                                                at android.app.BackStackRecord.remapSharedElements(BackStackRecord.java:1092)
                                                                                at android.app.BackStackRecord.configureTransitions(BackStackRecord.java:1299)
                                                                                at android.app.BackStackRecord.beginTransition(BackStackRecord.java:1011)
                                                                                at android.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:1566)
                                                                                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1519)
                                                                                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManager.java:495)
                                                                                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
                                                                                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:452)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6856)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

i find this question [NullPointerException related to FragmentManager.popBackStack. How to resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241649/nullpointerexception-related-to-fragmentmanager-popbackstack-how-to-resolve)

and the problem not occurs always, i faced it on Galaxy E5 (e53g)

please any help ..

Comment: add code of postesFragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved it.

Just using `supportFragmentManager` instead of `FragmentManager`
and `support.v4.fragment` instead of `app.fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.addToBackStack(null);

transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```

if it shows same problem then do not use

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack()
```

Comment: actually yes when i am using the popBackStackImmidiate() no exception throwed but the fragment still active and i have to call "popBackstatckImmidiate" twice

Comment: backpress automatically handle popBackStackImmidiate(), so do not use this

Answer (score 0):

Please give fragment's reference while calling setSharedElementReturnTransition and setExitTransition method. For instance,

```
    frg.setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(
                getActivity()).inflateTransition(R.transition.profile_image_transform));
    frg.setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(
                getActivity()).inflateTransition(R.transition.profile_image_transform));
```